# When did it become necessary to place verbs at the end of a subordinate clause?

Tags: verb, middle-high-german

In Middle High German, the position of verbs after conjunctions did not follow the present rules. In which historical period were these laid down?

Comment: MHD didn't have many "rules". It was a written language, not a spoken one (just like Latin), and it used the grammar rules of the dialects it evolved from (which were many, thus probably no rules at all). Also note most relicts we have today are poems, literature, and music - Those don't even have "rules" today.

Answer (score 3):

TL/DR: it was a gradual process, starting in OHG and being finished in the 18. century, the latest.

---

The following is really a summary of chapter 4.1.2 of [Historische Sprachwissenschaft des Deutschen](https://elibrary.narr.digital/book/99.125005/9783823390732) by Damaris Nübling.

The reason for this kind of phenomenon was a gradual shift of German syntax to the use of analytic constructions (articles, periphrastic tenses, modal verb constructions, etc.), many of which tend to put grammatical information in front of their lexical parts.  This is a change from the PIE "style" of inflectional morphology coming mostly after verbs and nouns, and lead to the development of today's complex [*Satzklammer*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satzklammer).

In OHG, all sentence orders were relatively freely usable, although information packaging played a role.  Verb-last order (VL) in subordinated sentences was already not infrequent.

In MHD (or at least since about the 11. century), verb-second order (V2) began to dominate in main sentences, and verb-first order to be dropped.  At the same time, complex *Satzklammer* was not too fashionable yet, but existed.  In subordinated clauses, VL order is not obligatory, but starts to get more frequent (74% in [Notker's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Notker_Labeo) psalter).

Then in early NHG, from about the 14. century onwards, VL started to become the norm in subordinated sentences, and the contrast between main + V2 and subordinated + VL was getting fully grammaticalized.  This went in hand with the further development of complex *Satzklammern* especially since the 16./17. century; it is not quite clear whether this was a feature of spoken or written language first, but it certainly was also quite present in spoken language too, as evidenced by pamphlets from the time.

In the 17. and 18. century, complexity of *Satzklammern* reached its peak, and from then on, VL order in subordinated clauses is fixed.  (I suppose this also has to do with the increasing standardization of norms due to printing and [*Kanzleisprachen*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanzleisprache).)

Comment: I suppose another consideration is that OHG and MHG were not monolithic entities. German and Dutch word orders have enough in common that one can assume that the change was well underway when they split. Apparently Yiddish and Icelandic allow V2 word order in all clauses.I personally like to think of German as VL, but in main clauses the verb is "moved" to V2. This isn't supported by the evidence, historical or otherwise, but to me it's a slightly simpler explanation what happens in modern German.